# How I can plot a bar plot like this

Tags: python, bar-chart, visualization

I have a data of purchases in years and months and days.
This data have 3 columns ("ClaimID, Agent, Creation_date")
I want to plot it like the image I am sharing somone guid me how this is possible.

I have got this but this is not good.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please complete the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You can do it using Matplotlib. All the best!

Comment: it looks like you forgot to post the code. what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)